# Querying NULL values from table - SQL

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a table which has a reference id column. This reference id column contains primary key for certain rows. Now i want to filter all the rest values containing NULL in them from table.
**TABLE**

```
PK   REFERENCE_ID
1        1
2        NULL
3        3
4        NULL
5        ab
```

The query below bring the result of all those which have reference_id but i want to fetch all the NULL values of REFERENCE_ID column

```
select count(*)from table where table.ID not in (select table.reference_id from person)
```

i have used exists also but no use. And it is important that i search it with reference to PK as i want to fetch all values including NULL values from column REFERENCE_ID other than PK.

Comment: Hmm, IS NULL? http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/isnull.php

Comment: @Adel Thanks but it is not what i require.

Comment: What does "search it with reference to PK" mean? And why is it important?

Comment: Based on your example data, what would you like the query to return?

Comment: I want to fetch all values including NULL values from column REFERENCE_ID other than PK.

Comment: do you mean, you want to fetch REFERENCE_ID values which are not in the PK column?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm still not clear on what you're trying to do, but would it work to combine elements of your original query with `IS NULL`?

```
SELECT PK, Reference_ID
FROM table 
WHERE table.Reference_ID NOT IN (select PK from table)
  OR table.Reference_ID IS NULL
```

**Edit:** I'm not sure about that 'ab' in the Reference_ID field. If Reference_ID is a varchar or similar field, you might need this instead:

```
SELECT PK, Reference_ID
FROM table 
WHERE table.Reference_ID NOT IN (select cast(PK as varchar(5)) from table)
  OR table.Reference_ID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
SELECT Reference_ID
FROM Table
WHERE Reference_ID IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks but its important that i search it with reference to PK.